# Android: setBackgroundColor without removing my drawable

Tags: android, xml, drawable

I have a button:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/male"
    android:id="@+id/btn_mgen_m"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_tgl_btn_left"
    android:textColor="#444444" />
```

and I changed its color like this:

```
btnMgenM = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_mgen_m);
btnMgenM.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        btnMgenM.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#dca8c3"));
    }
});
```

The background color is changed properly but it seems to remove the background drawable. The round radius, text color and border are removed
just the simple colored button is left.
I want to change the background color when I click this button, but not change anything else.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this both of line

```
btnMgenM.setBackgroundResource(0);
btnMgenM.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#dca8c3"));
```

Comment: I tried this. but button's shape(drawable background) is removed neither. I have to maintain shape/border but just change the background color

Answer (score 0):

You can do like the following :

create in your `res/drawable` `button_style.xml`

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_focused="true">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/colorGreyFirst" />
        <corners android:radius="16dp" />
        <stroke
            android:width="3dp"
            android:color="@color/colorBlackTransparent" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:state_selected="true">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/colorGreyFirst" />
        <corners android:radius="16dp" />
        <stroke
            android:width="3dp"
            android:color="@color/colorBlackTransparent" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/colorGreyFirst" />
        <corners android:radius="16dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/colorGrey" />
        <corners android:radius="16dp" />
        <stroke
            android:width="3dp"
            android:color="@color/colorGrey" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

and in your xml :

```
    <Button
android:layout_width="60dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/male"
android:id="@+id/btn_mgen_m"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
 android:background="@drawable/button_style"
android:textColor="#444444" />
```

and in your `color.xml` you could specify your colors.

Or you can simply do like that :

```
    btnMgenM = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_mgen_m);
btnMgenM.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        btnMgenM.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.yourColor));

    }
});
```

And add this to your color.xml

```
 <color name="yourColor"> #dca8c3</color>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Nice! good suggestion. but I have to change background color programmatically because some button should be color-toggled and some button changes other button's background color. Can I change this state_[action] programmatically?

Comment: I found it! What I need was setPressed(), SetSelected(). Thanks